# Matlab - calculate average of non-NaN frames

Tags: matlab, blob, average

I'm looking to detect the average speed of a blob once it is detected until it moves off the screen, I'm having trouble on how to set the boundary of what values to use.

Here is some example data:

```
#35 x_cen=NaN  y_cen=NaN  curSpeed=0
Elapsed time is 0.263965 seconds.
#36 x_cen=NaN  y_cen=NaN  curSpeed=0
Elapsed time is 0.263827 seconds.
#37 x_cen=NaN  y_cen=NaN  curSpeed=0
Elapsed time is 0.420120 seconds.
#38 x_cen=3.052941e+01  y_cen=1.147059e+01  curSpeed=0
Elapsed time is 0.302205 seconds.
#39 x_cen=30  y_cen=1.104167e+01  curSpeed=6.813593e-01
Elapsed time is 0.294330 seconds.
#40 x_cen=30  y_cen=1.104167e+01  curSpeed=6.813593e-01
Elapsed time is 0.281333 seconds.
#41 x_cen=30  y_cen=1.104167e+01  curSpeed=6.813593e-01
Elapsed time is 0.293527 seconds.
#42 x_cen=NaN  y_cen=NaN  curSpeed=0
Elapsed time is 0.272795 seconds.
#43 x_cen=NaN  y_cen=NaN  curSpeed=0
Elapsed time is 0.271102 seconds.
#44 x_cen=NaN  y_cen=NaN  curSpeed=0
```

In this example data I would like the average speed on the object starting from frame 39 to frame 41.

At the moment I can calcualte the average speed of a specified number of frames using the following code:

```
   avgSpeed = (curSpeed + sum(speedData(end-2:end))) / 4;
```

I'm planning to wrap the above line in an `if` statement if I can get a way to use varaible line numbers.

Comment: If you have a matrix containing all your data, you can use logical indexing to extracting the non-NaN values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to determine the number of frames and the average speed:

```
moving = false;
startFrame = 0;
endFrame = 0;
counter = 0;
        speedTotal = 0;
        if curSpeed > 0 && moving == false
            counter = counter + 1;
            speedTotal = speedTotal + curSpeed;
        elseif curSpeed == 0
            moving = false;
            avgSpeed = speedTotal / counter
            counter = 0;
            avgSpeed = 0;
            speedTotal = 0;
        end
```